# Display Message Box to copy code section from it using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, popup, powershell-2.0, nuget-package

I am building **install.ps1** script for Nuget pacakge and would like to open popup message at the end with some message , i have already achieved by following.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Test message ", "Test", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Information)
```

It will open popup message as per shown in below fig.

[image]

Instead of this i would like put some config code here that user can copy from box as per below fig

[image]

Please suggest me if anyone has done similar popup box before!

Comment: You want to provide the user a way to copy the message box text?

Comment: You got to create your own form for that.

Comment: What exactly is the goal here? Take a step back and tell us why you want the user to copy/paste something from a dialog. Can't you automate this some other way without user intervention? There are other ways to put text on the clipboard.

Comment: @x0n My goal was to put some code section in srvicedefination.csdef file of cloud project which is separate from the target project so i put popup to tell user to put this code by self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to customize `Windows.Forms.MessageBox` to add what your looking for. In order to do what your looking for you'll need to create a custom form. An easy way of doing this is to use Primal Forms Community Edition which can be found [here](http://www.sapien.com/downloads). You'll need to register for free to reach the download. There's a paid for version to so don't confuse that with the free CE edition. This tool gives you a Visual Studio like forms editor where you can drag and drop controls to a form and save the Powershell script. You'll need to create an event handler for the copy to text to clipboard button. After you saved the code generated by PrimalForms CE you will need to edit it to add the code for the event handlers. An example of how you can set the clip board with Powershell can be found [here](http://poshcode.org/2219).

[image: PrimalForms Community Edition Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Users can copy the message box text simply by pressing the Ctrl+C key combination.

Comment: I know that but i want allow users to select only some portion (code) from string + 3 lines code as per shown in fig