# Adding a link to document on a windows form

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell for synching my pc with a NAS (Robocopy), I want a popup message using Windows.Forms.MessageBox to inform the user when the destination has files that the source doesn't therefore they will be deleted from the destination (using /MIR). I want to place a link to the results of the Compare-Object file in my Message Box so the user can choose to open the file and see what will be erased before aknoleging to continue.

How can I place a link to a document on my message box?

`$d = [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Be careful! Source smaler than Destination, if you continue, data at destination will be erased. Do you wish to continue?", "Warning source smaller than destination", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo, [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best solution for you is to abandon the MessageBox and build your own DialogBox.

You can use [Sapiens PrimalForms Community Edition](http://www.sapien.com/downloads#Community%20Tools/32%20Bit/PrimalFormsCE.exe) (It's free, you just have to sign to Sapiens and go to download).This Framwork allow you to graphicaly build your DialogBox and then it generates the PowerShell Code for Windows Forms.

Comment: Thanks JP, I started using PrimalForms and it works perfectly for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to customize `Windows.Forms.MessageBox` beyond changing the icon, title, message and buttons. In order to add a link to the form you'll have to create a custom form. Heres how:

[Display Message Box to copy code section from it using Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653985/display-message-box-to-copy-code-section-from-it-using-powershell-script/8660418#8660418)